# how can i make this view in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview

i  want to make this type of for my view in my app . [image]

where i show user list and user can select  them after then user can recommend something on text view like Facebook ,Can any one suggest me or any example . Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion is that you try writing some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple. You will be having a view controller containing 2 view embedded in UINavigation controller to maintain the stack of pushed viewcontrollers in it. First View will be the above view containing static text "To", image for freinds and disclosure indicator "that arrow sign."

Than it will contain 2nd view which lies directly below the first view. It will be containing uiimageview which contains user profile picture and a UITextView which will contain the following text "What's on your mind." Initially it will be of gray color.

Further you have to implement delegate method of UITextView

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

It will help you out in changing color from gray to black when user will start writing and here you will set "What's on your mind" when user clear the textview.

On pressing the arrow button you will push the ViewController containing UITableView which will be the list of friends.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
```